# _ctypes not install when trying to import pandas

Tags: python, ctypes

I have read many questions online about trying to solve this issue but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

I get this error:

```
(venv) matt@localhost:~/Downloads/Python-3.11.3> python3
Python 3.11.3 (main, Apr 29 2023, 22:07:31) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.core.util.hashing import (  # noqa:F401
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/util/hashing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.base import _registry as registry
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.errors import AbstractMethodError
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/errors/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I am running opensuse leap 15.4
I have installed `libffi`.

```
S  | Name          | Summary                                   | Type
---+---------------+-------------------------------------------+--------
i+ | libffi-devel  | Include files for development with libffi | package
i  | libffi7       | Foreign Function Interface Library        | package
i  | libffi7-32bit | Foreign Function Interface Library        | package
i+ | uwsgi-libffi  | Plugin libffi for uWSGI                   | package
```

I have tried to reinstall python

```
cd MyPythonDownloadDIR
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make install
```

I have tried other things also without any luck. If any body has any idea?

I can't run `pandas` in python or in a virtual environment.

Comment: `_ctypes` - This is built-in module of python. I will suggest reinstalling python might fix this.

You can also install - `libffi-dev`

Answer (score 1):

Install libffi-dev:

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```

Then Re-Install desired python version.

Steps are mentioned [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652).

This has been resolved [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1183)